# Sharing data with $resource and an optional parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-services

I am trying to share data between controllers - my side nav controller with a list of tables and my main controller witch controls the table itself..

my service is pretty simple:

```
.factory('TableData', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('api/db/:table', {table: '@table'}, {
            'save':   {method:'POST'},
            'update': { method:'PUT' },
            'delete':{method:'DELETE'},
            'list': {method: 'GET', isArray: true },
            'getTable': {method: 'GET', isArray: true }
        });
}])
```

and the controllers:

```
.controller('SideNavController', function ($scope, $http, $state, $auth, Account, $stateParams, Tables, $rootScope, TableData) {



    TableData.list().$promise.then(function(tables){
        $scope.tables = tables;
    });

    $scope.getTable = function(table){
        TableData.getTable({table:table}).$promise.then(function(table){
            $scope.selectedTable = table;
        });
    }
});
```

and the main controller:

```
.controller('ManagerCtrl', function($scope, $auth, Account, $http, $rootScope, ParamData, UserData, DocParamData, DocTypeData, ParamTypeData, ParamValueData, SysParamValuesData, TableData ) {

    $scope.selectedTable = TableData.getTable();
})
```

how would i share this data? how can i pass th `table` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can associate table with $rootScope and since it is the parent scope of all the $scope in angular therefore table can be accessible both of the controllers.

### Code:

.controller('SideNavController', function ($scope, $http, $state, $auth, Account, $stateParams, Tables, $rootScope, TableData) {

```
TableData.list().$promise.then(function(tables){
    $scope.tables = tables;
});

$scope.getTable = function(table){
    TableData.getTable({table:table}).$promise.then(function(table){
        $rootScope.selectedTable = table;
    });
}
```

});

Now this $rootScope.selectedTable can be accessed in both of the controllers.

Second way, You can write one angular service where you can put getTable() method.

### Code:

app.service('MyService', function($http, TableData) {
    this.getTable = function(table, callback){
        TableData.getTable({table:table}).$promise.then(function(table){
            callback(table);
        });
    }
});

Now you can inject this service and call getTable() method which would pass table obj to callback.

```
.controller('ManagerCtrl', function($scope, $auth, Account, $http, $rootScope, ParamData, UserData, DocParamData, DocTypeData, ParamTypeData, ParamValueData, SysParamValuesData, TableData, MyService ) {

    MyService.getTable(table, function(table) {
        $scope.selectedTable = table;
    });
})
```